Random effect nested in two crossed fixed factors
I have presence/absence diagnoses from 20 doctors for each of 50 samples from 5 patients (10 samples from each patient which differ according to two factors). The doctors are one of three specialist qualifications (early-training, late-training, or fully-trained) and in two fields (surgery and radiology). These are crossed (there are doctors from each level of qualification in each field). How can I incorporate doctor as a random factor which is nested in both qualification and field?
I tried this:
g1 <- glmmTMB(
  Diagnosis ~ Patient_factor_1 + Patient_factor_2 + Qualification + Field + 
    (1 | PatientID/TestID) + (1 | Qualification:Doctor)  + (1 | Field:Doctor),
  data = dat,
  family = binomial())

but got a model convergence error.
